# How to use a "dummy" (updated via elapsed time) progress bar while using backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, progress-bar, backgroundworker

Working, updated code at the bottom (edit). Thank you, roryap

---

My program is fairly simple.

You click a button and it performs a task. The task uses an XML exporter for a large table of data. However, it takes a long time due to database distance. It is *not* iterative so I can't do multiple ProgressChanged calls and I want users to be able to use the rest of the interface during this time.

This poses a problem. Depending on the order being processed, it could have multiple lines per order. Each line takes roughly a minute. What I want is a progress bar (and elapsed timer) to update while the backgroundworker is running.

This is an example of what I'm currently doing:

```
Private Sub GenerateXMLFiles()
    'Perform a single large, slow task here:
    ExportToXML(dgvDataGrid)
    dPercentComplete = ((dgvDataGrid.Rows.Count * 60) - swTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) / 100
    UpdateStatus(dPercentComplete, MillisecondsToHMS(swTimer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds))
End Sub

Private Sub btnGenerateXMLFiles_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateXMLFiles.Click
    barProgress.Value = 0
    barProgress.Minimum = 0
    barProgress.Maximum = 100
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    btnGenerateXMLFiles.Enabled = False
    swTimer.Start()
    GenerateXMLFiles()
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub UpdateStatusDelegate()
    Friend Sub UpdateStatus()
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New UpdateStatusDelegate(AddressOf UpdateStatus), New Object() {})
        Else
            dProgress = ((dgvDataGrid.Rows.Count * 60) - swTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) / 100
            barProgress.Value = CInt(dProgress)
            lblElapsedTimeFill.Text = MillisecondsToHMS(swTimer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    If Not (e.Error Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox(e.Error.Message)
    End If

    barProgress.Value = 100
    btnGenerateXMLFiles.Enabled = True
    swTimer.Stop()

    swTimer.Reset()
    EnableAllButtons()
    bgWorker.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Function MillisecondsToHMS(ByVal ms As Double) As String
    Dim ts As TimeSpan
    Dim totHrs As Integer
    Dim H, M, S, HMS As String

    ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms)
    totHrs = Math.Truncate(ts.TotalHours)
    H = Format(totHrs, "0#") & ":"
    M = Format(ts.Minutes, "0#") & ":"
    S = Format(ts.Seconds, "0#")
    HMS = H & M & S

    Return HMS
End Function
```

---

This clearly doesn't work as it won't update the Progress Bar and Elapsed Time but a single time before or after doing the large call.

So the goal is to just have the progress bar take ~60 seconds to fill per order I pass it, since it's quite close to that anyway.

This leads me to believe that I may have to have a separate thread handle the progress bar and timer, but I'm not sure what problems that poses or if it will update regardless. Maybe I'm over thinking this?

Thanks for any help or advice you all can offer!

---

### Update: working!

```
Private Sub ThreadGenerateXMLFiles()
    'Significant time-consuming XML export function
End Sub

Private Sub btnGenerateXMLFiles_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateXMLFiles.Click
    barProgress.Value = 0
    tTimer.Start()
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False 'This is not smart, but time is limited
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.DoWork
    btnGenerateXMLFiles.Enabled = False
    swTimer.Start()
    ThreadGenerateXMLFiles()
End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    If Not (e.Error Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox(e.Error.Message)
    End If

    btnGenerateXMLFiles.Enabled = True
    DisableGeneratingXMLOverlay()
    swTimer.Stop()
    swTimer.Reset()
    tTimer.Stop()
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
    EnableAllButtons()
    bgWorker.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Function MillisecondsToHMS(ByVal ms As Double) As String
    Dim ts As TimeSpan
    Dim totHrs As Integer
    Dim H, M, S, HMS As String

    ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms)
    totHrs = Math.Truncate(ts.TotalHours)
    H = Format(totHrs, "0#") & ":"
    M = Format(ts.Minutes, "0#") & ":"
    S = Format(ts.Seconds, "0#")
    HMS = H & M & S
    Return HMS
End Function

Private Sub tTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tTimer.Tick
    lblElapsedTimeFill.Text = MillisecondsToHMS(swTimer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
    barProgress.Value = (swTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / 70) * 100.0 '~70s per line
End Sub
```

---

Updating the progress bar and timer outside of the backgroundworker thread, which should have been obvious and yet somehow wasn't.

Comment: The working code would be much more useful if a distinction could be made between "swTimer" and "tTimer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you've stated, you don't need to tie the progress bar to the background worker, you can simply update the progress bar on the UI thread without too much difficulty.  I would recommend using the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class.  Every time it ticks, you can use that to update the progress bar.

Comment: Okay, so I was being stupid and over(under) thinking it. That makes sense and I'm not sure why I was so hung up on putting it in the background thread in the first place. However, when I added a timer, and created a function that "Handles tTimer.Tick", it gets in there every tick and updates both my elapsed time and progress percentage, but it's not visibly writing that to the UI. Am I missing some sort of repaint call or something? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure; I think you'll have to show some code (i.e. update your question with the new code you have).

Comment: I got it, I'll update my post in a minute. I had my tTimer.Start() in wrong spot. Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: oh, but now you're generating the XML files in your UI thread :\ this is poor design. it'll lock the UI.

Comment: @porkchop -- Not so; he's only updating the progress bar on the UI thread.  The background worker is still the same as before w.r.t. the XML generation.

Comment: oh so now he's updating the `dPercentComplete` member from another thread, which isn't threadsafe ;o infact, that's failing, its the `UpdateStatus` right after that that is doing the work ;o unless `dPercentComplete` is `Shared`, i don't see how that's working. and that requires a lock. in fact, now you're trying to update it twice, and the timer method is actually failing, since the variable you're refering is a copy in another thread ;o

Comment: @porkchop That first bit of code I posted wasn't in fact working for my purpose. I basically didn't want or need my progress bar or elapsed timer being updated via the backgroundworker. In fact, it couldn't be as my backgroundworker was only calling a single function in which I couldn't track the progress of, therefore not be able to report that progress to backgroundworker. If that makes sense. Please see my edited code at the bottom of the post. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @Keith there, i fixed my example. correct  method. that's not the point, you're creating a `race condition`.

Comment: You're right, but please read my reply above you. Calling UpdateStatus simply wouldn't work for my background worker since it'd only be called once either before or after my slow, *single* function call. If I were doing some sort of iterative loop or calling many functions, I would use that UpdateStatus throughout, but I'm not. I'm only calling one function.

Comment: @Keith try to access `dPercentComplete` from the UI thread. it returns nothing or 0, right? that's because it's being updated in the wrong thread. plus a bunch of other issues i see with this code. actually, i just realized, i don't even know where your DGV object is... and also you're starting the timer in the wrong thread, wait no... you're starting 2 dif timers? :\ some called in the wrong thread, you start `swTimer` in thread2, and stop it in thread1?

Answer (score 2):

not sure about your progressbar code, but this should be:

```
Private Delegate Sub UpdateStatusDelegate()
Friend Sub UpdateStatus()
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New UpdateStatusDelegate(AddressOf UpdateStatus), New Object() {})
        Else
            dProgress = ((dgvDataGrid.Rows.Count * 60) - swTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) / 100
            barProgress.Value = CInt(dProgress)
            lblElapsedTimeFill.Text = MillisecondsToHMS(swTimer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
        End If
End Sub
```

Instead, it should be in `UpdateStatus`.. whatever you want to update from another thread needs to be there.

Comment: Oops, thank you. Unfortunately, I can't use this method at all, as it only updates a single time, making the progress bar fairly useless.

Comment: @Keith you have 2 `UpdateStatus()` functions left in your code example above.

Comment: Fixed. My bad (again)